# SQL to HiveQL in Hive Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, impala

I am trying to write a HiveQL query which joins two data sets by a BAN column where one datasets timestamp is 72+ hours after the other datasets timestamp.  I can write this in SQL but the syntax isn't the same in HiveQL.  Can anyone help?

For example :

```
SELECT * FROM Session_Step_Table, Case_Table
WHERE Session_Step_Table.BAN = Case_Table.BAN AND
  DATEADD(hour, 72, Session_Step_Table.timestamp) <= Case_Table.timestamp
```

Comment: Hive doesn't support non-equi-joins. Provide your exact requirement and some sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use date_add() function provided in Hive. Look [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions)